# Connecting to oracle database located remotely

Tags: oracle, netbeans, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to run following code which is connecting to remote database and retrieving records:

```
   import java.sql.*;

   class Employee
   {
     public static void main (String args [])
      throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Load the Oracle JDBC driver
     Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

   // Connect to the database
    // You must put a database name after the @ sign in the connection URL.
    // You can use either the fully specified SQL*net syntax or a short cut
    // syntax as <host>:<port>:<sid>.  The example uses the short cut syntax.
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection  ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ourcompany.com:1521:course", "username", "password");

// Create a Statement
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();

// Select the ENAME column from the EMP table
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery ("select * from test");

// Iterate through the result and print the employee names
/*
while (rset.next ())
  System.out.println (rset.getString ("name"));
  System.out.println (rset.getString ("id"));
  */
  rset.next();
  System.out.println(rset.getString("name"));
```

}
}

after running this code from Netbeans i am getting an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@ourcompany.com:1521:course
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
>       at Employee.main(Emplyoee.java:23)
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

I have downloaded ojdbc14.jar and kept in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib path.
I do not know where i am going wrong?...plz help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this driver:

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

Check your classpath in Netbeans:

How to set classpath in NetBeans:

In NetBeans Project Properties Window, you click Libraries in the left panel, and in the right panel are 4 categories of classpath you can configure:

1. Compile: Empty by default. Compile-time libraries are automatically
   propagated to other categories of classpath, so you don't need to
   repeat the same set of jar files in all 4 categories.
2. Run: By default includes everything in compile-time classpath, and
   compiled classes (e.g., build/classes).
3. Compile Tests: By default includes everything in compile-time
   classpath, compiled classes (e.g., build/classes), and JUnit.
4. Run Tests: By default includes classpath for compiling tests, and
   compiled tests.

Comment: are you sure the jar file is in your classpath?

Comment: do I have to set the CLASSPATH using command line:                           C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses\myclasses.jar

Comment: So where do i have to add ojdbc6.jar file? Run Tests option?

Comment: i added ojdbc6.jar file in compile pane and ran the code...it got connected and output i got is as follow:                                   run:
Trying to connect...
connected!
SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch

Answer (score 1):

You are using awfully old version of Oracle JDBC driver. You should be using ojdbc6.jar.